# Matplotlib - Plot data in square shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a scatter plot of (x,y) values where the x axis limits are `[0, 10]` and the y-axis limits are `[0, 250]`. The outer shape of the plot is supposed to be square, so the unit length of both axis has to be different.

I have tried both `ax.axis('square')` and `ax.axis('equal')` , before and after setting the axis limits (set by `ax.set_xbound()` and `ax.set_ybound()`) but none of these combinations produces my desired outcome.

```
x = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
y = np.random.randint(0,250,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)

ax.set_xbound(0,10)
ax.set_ybound(0,250)
ax.axis('square')

plt.show()
```

Outcome with `ax.axis('square')`:
[image: square]

The shape of the plot is square but now the x and y limits are both `[0,250]`

Comment: show us what youre getting

Comment: What about `ax.set_aspect(1/250)` (for the original question)? Or `10/250` for the case of the example code?

Comment: @JohanC this gives the correct image, unfortunately it creates a huge spacing in between the plot area and its title.

Comment: You can use `ax.set_title('my title')` to set a title for the subplot.  You can set a figsize more appropriate to the desired square plot via `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(..., ...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axes.set_box_aspect` if you have reasonably recent matplotlib:
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
y = np.random.randint(0,250,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y)

ax.set_xbound(0,10)
ax.set_ybound(0,250)
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image]